# How can I store an image to the database from modal?

Tags: html, laravel, modal-dialog

I want to store an Image through a modal, usually, I store images this way. But it never stores, it stores null on the database, like the file wasn't even uploaded. Everything else on the modal stores perfectly, except the image.

This is the code for the image on my controller.

```
 if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() .'.'.$extension;
            $file->move('uploads/event/',$filename);
            $event->image = $filename;
        }
```

In my view, this is how I upload the image.

```
 <div class="text-center">
                            <img src='http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'  width="300px" height="300px" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar" name="image" >
                        </div><hr>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="image" >
                                <label class="custom-file-label">Upload picture</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: when you upload an image, is it saved on a folder somewhere on your server?

Comment: You should use the Storage class on your backend: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas yes! 
When I store from a normal view the images get saved to a folder, but I'm having trouble storing them from the Modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your Controller:

```
use Image;
    public function store(CreateRequest $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $imagename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $imageext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = 'upload/image/'.time().'.'.$imageext;
        $image = Image::make($file);
        $image->save($path);
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['image'] = $path;
        $user = $this->userRepository->create($input);
        return redirect(route('users.index'));
    }
```

do the same with `update()` function

The file will store in `/public/upload/image` folder

Answer (score 1):

For the code I had, the only problem was that I didn't use the enctype="multipart/form-data". After looking for options, I found this and wrote it on the form of action and form-group div. It worked, the image stores and it also updates.

```
  <form action="{{action('CalendarController@store')}}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Since I got this working I will start implementing other codes for better performance and start to learn about the Storage in laravel. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score -1):

You can also try and use the 'Intervention\Image' and `File` class:

```sh
composer require intervention/image
```

```php
<?php
...

use File;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image

...


if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = 'image.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $save_path = storage_path().'uploads/event/';
    $path = $save_path.$filename;
    $public_path = 'uploads/event/'.$filename;

    // Make the user a folder and set permissions
    File::makeDirectory($save_path, $mode = 0755, true, true);

    // Save the file to the server
    Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save($save_path.$filename);

    // Save the public image path
    $event->image = $public_path;
    $event->save();
}

    return response()->json(['path' => $path], 200);
} else {
    return response()->json(false, 200);
}
```